# find out if I am 20 years before I can sustain myself on the side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have sat and work with a small jquery sciprt to specify the speed at which age and whether you can get laws to create a user.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(function() {
    var today = new Date();     
    var dd = today.getDate(); 
    var mm = today.getMonth();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();     

    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "da" ] );      
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({       
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
        changeMonth: true,          
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1950:'+yyyy,
        maxDate: new Date(yyyy, mm, dd),

        onSelect: function(value, ui) {             
            var dob = new Date(value);
            var age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;
            $('#age').html(age+' år gammel');

            // alders kontrol
            var status = (age<20)? true: false;                         
            $('#msg').html( (! status )? '': 'Kan ikke opret dig!' );
            $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", status); 
        }
    });     
});
```

from present day and 20 years behind you can not select a date that it must be so. For example if I am 19 years today and I will be 20 tomorrow so I can first create me in the morning then you will see it.

so it must first come forward and find out whether you can create on the site, if you are over 20 years must go on to say how old you are,

The problem: is that it shows all years and dates and months from today back to 1950.
it must take yearling away from today and 20 years behind all of 1993, the last year be promoting. so it should be like that all the time you have to be 20 years before you have to register on the site.

Comment: So you want to show the calendar up to 20 years in the past as from right now, correct ?

Comment: The question seems legitimate, but difficult to understand (which is probably why you are getting downvotes)

Comment: Try to focus your question a bit more on the specific problem you are trying to solve.  Some of the additional detail makes it harder to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 maxDate: new Date(yyyy, mm, dd),
```

to

```
  maxDate: new Date(yyyy-20, mm, dd),
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/D6qkY/1/)